# Default size of action item in actionbar in percent

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to know which default size an MenuItem with an icon (drawable) has.
I need the percentage in relation to the actionbar width (screen width).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single action bar icon is [32x32dp](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).

As a percentage of the screen, it's impossible to say. Different devices have different screen widths.